# Tell Selector to return array inside array

Tags: jquery

```
$('.data').has(':checkbox:checked').find('.name, .street1, .street2, .county, .city, .postal, .country');
```

Returns 7 elements inside object in format of `[name, street, street2, county, city, postal, country]`

But in case if I have more than 1 set of these 7 elements on my page, it will return 14, 21, 28 and so on inside **still one single** object in a row without any separators.

Is there any way I can iterate through every 7 elements? Tell selector to return me object inside object with 7 elements? ie `[[name, street, street2, county, city, postal, country], [name, street, street2, county, city, postal, country]]` and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make multiple data class elements

html

```
<div class="data">1-7</div>
<div class="data">1-7</div>
<div class="data">1-7</div>
```

js

```
var dataArrays = [];
$('.data').has(':checkbox:checked').each(function(){
 dataArrays.push($(this).find('.name, .street1, .street2, .county, .city, .postal, .country'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `each` method on `.data`, you could iterate through the items:

```
$('.data').has(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var vals = $(this).find('.name, .street1, .street2, .county, .city, .postal, .country');
    some_function(vals);
});
```

You may have to restructure the way the result is used, but this is the more standard jQuery format.